# Using KNN to compare to dataframes

Tags: python, knn

I have the following two datasets:

```
import pandas as pd
from scipy.spatial import distance

all = {'test' : [0.3, 0.9],
 'call' : [0.2, 1.3],
 'category': ["A", "B"]}

all = pd.DataFrame(all)

df = pd.DataFrame()
df = df.append({'test': 0.2, 'call': 0.4}, ignore_index=True)
```

Based on these data.frames I would like to check to which category df is closer: category A or B.

Therefore I did the following:

Make the all data.frame numeric

```
all_numeric = all[[ 'test', 'call']]
```

Calculate the euclidean distance

```
euclidean_distances = all_numeric.apply(lambda row: distance.euclidean(row, df), axis=1)
distance_frame = pd.DataFrame(data={"dist": euclidean_distances, "idx": euclidean_distances.index})
distance_frame.sort("dist", inplace=True)
print(distance_frame)
```

And next I would like to look up the value in the all data.frame

```
lookup_value = distance_frame.iloc[0]['idx']
question = all['category'][0]
print("This customer content is labeled as %s" % question)
```

However if I try this with

```
df = pd.DataFrame()
df = df.append({'test': 0.9, 'call': 1.3}, ignore_index=True)
```

I should print "labeled as B" so I assume something goes wrong. Could anybody tell me wehre I go wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You are doing:

`question = all['category'][0]` which picks the first row in the column 'category' instead of the index (lookup_value) that you selected.

You should instead have:

`question = all['category'].loc[lookup_value]`

Overall, while this works, I would encourage you to rewrite this using numpy. Pandas is very powerful but if you find yourself operator on pairwise records (Cartesian product of all and df), then numpy will be result in a much cleaner and faster solution. If you need an example, please let me know and I'll be happy to provide one here.

EDIT:

Definitely, here's one way:

```
    import numpy as np
    from scipy.spatial import distance

    center_features = np.array([[0.3, 0.9], [0.2, 1.3]])
    center_labels = ["A", "B"]

    test_features = np.array([[0.2, 0.4], [0.9, 1.3]])

    for t in test_features:
        print t, center_labels[np.argmin([distance.euclidean(t, c) for c in center_features])]
```

The loop `[distance.euclidean(t, c) for c in center_features]` calculates the distance between a fixed example (df) and the labeled vectors.

np.argmin(x) gives you the index of the minimum element. So, `np.min([3,1,0,2])` gives 0 but `np.argmin([3,1,0,2]) gives 2 which is the index of 0.

Comment: thanks for your answer. Yes I would love an example.

Comment: Hope that helps! :)